# $\vert f(x)\vert$ is differentiable at $x=a$ then $f(x)$ is also differentiable at $x=a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> $\vert f(x)\vert$ is differentiable at $x=a$ then $f(x)$ is also differentiable at $x=a$

Is the above statement always true? If not, can you give an example?

$|x|$ and $x$ are both differentiable at $x=2$. The reverse is not always true. The example is $|x|$ itself. $y=x$ is differntiable at $x=0$ but $|x|$ is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x<=0\\ -1 & x>0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I never thought of a signum function. So the problem occurs when $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $a$ while $f'(x)$ is always $0$.

Comment: @AlexS $x^2$ is a bad example (you get enough decay at zero to have differentiability in that case). $e^x$ would be a better example (or anything else which has a definite sign and is differentiable near zero with f'(0) not zero).

Comment: @Ian, yes, you are right. Such is the peril of hasty example construction.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true: for instance if $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $a$ but it is always equal to $-1$ or $1$, then $|f(x)|=1$ is differentiable at $a$. This is actually a good example to keep in your toolbox, something very similar pops up when you talk about Riemann integrability and Lebesgue integrability.

If you assume $f$ is continuous at $a$ then I think this is actually true. Consider splitting into cases between whether $f$ changes sign near $a$ or not. When it doesn't, the situation is simple; when it does you need to think a bit.

Comment: Yes, it's true if $f$ is continuous at $a$. If $f(a)\ne0$ then either $|f|=f$ near $a$ or $|f|=-f$ near $a$. On the other hand, if $f(a)=0$ and $|f|$ is differentiable at $a$ then the derivative of $|f|$ must be $0$, and it follows easily that $f'(a)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f$ with $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$. Then $|f(x)|$ is constant $1$, i.e. differentiable at $0$ but $f$ is not.

Comment: 2 People where faster then me. :)